# File based database via smb

Tags: sqlite, networks

We currently have a hotel and a restaurant management software (named **Top-Sys** and **Pointex CHR**), and they are working completely without server software.

These are designed to be installed locally but their databases are located in shared folders, currently installed on a Synology NAS and shared over smb. Now, I'm developing a replacement software for both of us, to keep the same architecture, I thought about working with `sqlite` but [they strongly discourage sharing a database over the network](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/useovernet.html) because of a possibly buggy file locking mechanism.

Fine, but how do file-system-based databases work then? The same bugs making `sqlite` unsafe over the net also make other apps unsafe, but we never had any issues about concurrency and loss of data/data overwritten since we have them (around 15 years).

Comment: So you know all your customers use a Synology NAS, having a fast and stable LAN? Noone a VPN over some unreliable internet channel?

Comment: That’s not about VPN or fast LAN, we currently are in this situation and I was wondering how these apps were working. Thanks to the selected answer, I understand there is no magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local file handling and network access may be subtly different in hard to reproduce ways. Often such warnings about not using network files for databases (where integrity is of utmost importance) stem from incidents caused by slightly buggy implementations in slightly unreliable networks under highly concurrent access patterns. Since the network file access is not under the database vendor's control, it is safer to discourage using network files, even if in many cases they can be used successfully for years.

My general advice would be to stay away from network-shared file based databases and implement a proper service (using a server database). But I can see that for small applications with few users this seems to be overkill...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I understood why it’s discouraged. And it’s valid. I just don’t understand how these softwares manage to work perfectly in this way. Are they “waiting to fail”, or maybe they implement multiple database in a way each service only use one, something like this?

Comment: I'd guess they are "waiting to fail", where fail might never happen (or at least so rarely that it's lost in the noise of other inexplicable software/hardware failures).

Comment: If such a network failure occurs more seldom than a hardware failure, that's pretty reliable.